# Why there are an ios folder on my app android on Android Studio?

Tags: ios, android-studio, ionic-framework, apk

So I need to upload an app ionic to Google Play and Apple Store. I use
Capatitor. What I did do:

- Install Cocoapods, Ruby, Ionic
- These command line : $ionic build, $ionic cap add ios, $ionic cap add android, $ionic cap copy, $ionic cap sync, $ionic cap open ios, $ionic cap open android.

My problem:

- When Android Studio opens, there are one folder appointed "capatitor-ios-app-traking". But this folder block me for build APK.

Someone would have an explanation for this?

Comment: Probably related to this $ionic cap open ios

Comment: "$ionic cap open ios" open my app on Xcode, so I don't think it comes from there. And even if I only make the command : "$ionic cap open android" for open my app only on Android Studio, I have the same problem.